# JSON.NET interfering with MSChart dates

Tags: c#, multithreading, json.net, mschart

## Problem

i've run into an issue where deserializing any value with json.net (even dummy values) seems to mess up the dates along the x-axis of my mschart control. this is a chart that's supposed to have date values along the x-axis:

===bad===

[image]

the chart is produced by the following minimal code:

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Threading;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Thread thread;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        chart1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        thread = new Thread(Plot);
        thread.Start();
    }

    void Plot()
    {
        // prepare chart
        chart1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            chart1.ChartAreas.Clear();
            chart1.Series.Clear();

            ChartArea area = new ChartArea();
            chart1.ChartAreas.Add(area);

            Series series = new Series("water level");
            series.ChartArea = area.Name;
            series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            chart1.Series.Add(series);
        });

        // plot line by adding 2 points: ((time)0, 0) and ((time)1, 1)
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            object dummy = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>("null");

            chart1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                DateTime time = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, i, DateTimeKind.Utc);

                chart1.Series["water level"].Points.AddXY(time, i);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

commenting out the only json.net line following line results in the expected result:

```
object dummy = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>("null");
```

===good===

[image]

## Question

is there something wrong with my code?

## Update

i just replaced the concerned line with

```
Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

and the problem still occurs. i thought that maybe i'm modifying the chart too early. but now, i'm not sure what to make of it.

Comment: I suspect it is screwing with your culture in some way. What are is the value of `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` before and after the json.net call?

Comment: it's "en-US" before and after

Comment: I can reproduce this too. Very odd.

Comment: oh. that's "good". then it's not a local problem

Comment: i don't think the issue is caused specifically by json.net. i just tried it with my own json parser and the same thing happens

Answer (score 0):

i had a look through the properties of the Series object, and saw that XValueType was set to "Double". so i tried explicitly setting it to "DateTime" when creating it, and that solved the problem:

```
Series series = new Series("water level");
series.ChartArea = area.Name;
series.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime; /* <---- added this line */
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
chart1.Series.Add(series);
```

it is set to "Auto" by default, which appareantly does not always get set to "DateTime". i guess i should have looked at the properties much earlier.

it's still a strange issue to me, and i have no idea what causes it, so this is more of a workaround.